# Fatal error in Android 9 : Frequently crashes when switching between Screens

Tags: android, mobile

I am experiencing this 'Fatal error' issue in the Android application.
Can someone please share with me the correct reason behind this kind of error on the mobile phone?

I referred to so many documents/Questions in stackoverflow but couldn't find the perfect one.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1003060 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending some large text to Fragment using Bundle. Clear it after receiving data

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data", "Your large text...");
```

In Fragment **onViewCreated**

```
String recData = bundle.get("data");       
bundle.clear();
```

Or **Override onSaveInstanceState in your Fragment**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle oldInstanceState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(oldInstanceState);
    oldInstanceState.clear();
}
```

I hope it can help for your problem.